# No overload matches this call in jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am new to react and jest and I am not using enzyme right now

The error I am facing is No overload matches this call.
'Overload 1 of 2, '(props: XProperty| Readonly ): BuildingUnit', gave the following error.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly': ab, cd
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: XProperty, context: any): BuildingUnit', gave the following error.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly': ab, cd'

**Class BuildingUnit:**

```
    type XProperty= { ab, cd};
    type YProperty= {ef, gh};
    
        class BuildingUnit extends React.Component<XProperty, YProperty>{
        
             methodA(){
            
             }
             Method B(){
       
             }
             render(){
           <input text onChange={this.MethodA}>
             }
        }
export default BuildingUnit;
```

when I try to get a text from the label through rendering, it throws an error of 'No overload matches this call'
and I also want to know how can I access MethodA() in BuildUnitTest for the assertion
**BuildUnit.test.js**:

```
import BuildingUnit  from './BuildingUnit';
import React, { useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

test('Validation', ()=>{
    
    const root = document.createElement("div");
    const {getByText, getByLabelText}= render(<BuildingUnit/>);
  
})
```

Comment: It sounds like you really have two questions here. If I understand correctly, you're having trouble getting the component to work because it thinks it doesn't have the correct props? And the second question is how you can directly test `MethodA`? I'd like to see more details around the first question. I'm not clear if it is an issue in the tests or in the source code itself.

Comment: no, the source code is working fine without any issue. it has correct props. but my question is when I try to use 'render(<BuildingUnit/>)', it gives me an error of prop type missing. so how can I define props type in the test class

Answer (score 0):

## No Overload Matches...

I find it odd that you're receiving this at all given that you've indicated your `BuildingUnit.spec.js` file is a `.js` and not a `.ts`. Setting that oddity aside, the fact is that you're not providing `BuildingUnit` any props in your test code:

```
const {getByText, getByLabelText}= render(<BuildingUnit/>);
```

But in your source code you've created the BuildingUnit class and typed its props to have two keys, `ab` and `cd`:

```
    type XProperty= { ab, cd};
    type YProperty= {ef, gh};
    
    class BuildingUnit extends React.Component<XProperty, YProperty>{
        // ...
    }
```

Emphasis on the `React.Component<XProperty //, ...>` bit.

In test, you can assign props just like you do in your source code, and you'll need to do it for your tests to work:

```
const {getByText, getByLabelText}= render(<BuildingUnit ab="some ab value" cd="some cd value" />);
```

## How Can You Access methodA for Testing

### TL;DR

You probably shouldn't directly access methodA. You've already pulled in `react-testing-library` so use it to [interact with your component](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro#act) and then assert on what changes happen.

So, if BuildingUnit renders a `textarea` use `react-testing-library` to type in that textarea and then assert on what happens. If `methodA`, for instance, should trigger a call to an API on change, mock that API using `jest.fn()` and then `expect(myAPI.postChanges).toHaveBeenCalled()` or similar.

Apologies for the general recommendations, but the code sample is very general, so not a lot to go on, but the bottom line is that `react-testing-library` encourages you to interact with components the way your users would (by typing, clicking, etc.) and then testing what happens. The UI is the public interface of a React component, and that's what you should be testing.

### More Details

You'll find some variance in philosophy here, but the generally accepted practice is that you should only be testing the public API of your code. If this was Java or something and you were creating classes with `public` or `private` methods, you COULD NOT AND SHOULD NOT test the `private` methods directly. They are implementation details.

The waters are a bit muddier when you get to Javascript, because `public` and `private` are not so clearly defined in many cases, but as stated above, the public interface of your React components are the UI that's being rendered, so that's *really* what you should test.

Testing methodA directly also means your test will now become brittle. When you want to refactor your component, if you directly test methodA it will now become difficult to do refactoring without needing to change your tests. Testing the behavior of the component as a whole, though, means you can refactor to your heart's content without needing to change the tests. If the tests pass (assuming they're good tests), your refactoring was safe and you haven't broken any functionality, even if you've separated methodA into 20 different methods (i.e. implementation details)

*If* you insist upon directly testing `methodA`, Enzyme should allow you to do this, using `instance.methodA()` once you've mounted/shallow mounted the component. See [this documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html#react-16x) for a brief example.

Just be aware of the above issues about brittle tests and testing implementation details. Also, at last check, Enzyme didn't support hooks well (and you really should be writing functional hooks components rather than class-based components for all new components), so directly testing methodA may be impossible along with impractical.

Best of luck.